# Property 'window' not found on object of type 'CustomTabBar'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

What I want to do is customize the text and images of the `UITabBarItem`s in my iOS app.  I figured I would do this by subclassing `UITabBarController` with the `CustomTabBar` class.

When I try to do it with the below code, I get an error stating: `Property 'window' not found on object of type 'CustomTabBar'`. How can I correctly subclass `UITabBarController` so that I can customize the text and images?

**CustomTabBar.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <Parse/PFCloud.h>

@interface CustomTabBar : UITabBarController

@end
```

**CustomTabBar.m:**

```
#import "CustomTabBar.h"

@interface CustomTabBar ()

@end

@implementation CustomTabBar

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Assign tab bar item with titles
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];

    tabBarItem1.title = @"Search";
    tabBarItem2.title = @"MatchCenter";
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted is in your tab bar controller subclass, so the tab bar controller is just "self".

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBar;
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];

    tabBarItem1.title = @"Search";
    tabBarItem2.title = @"MatchCenter";
}
```